# how to reinitialize the angular.firebase.config() in angular 8

Tags: angular8

we have existing details deleted and reinitlise the  AngularFireModule.initializeApp()

we create one firebase service change the country selection we change the dynamically firebase config
when use AngularFireModule.apps[0].delete(); we got errors